# Wifi dongle unavailble in nmcli

Tags: fedora, wifi, networkmanager, nmcli

I have a realtek usb dongle plugged in to my Intel Compute Stick that's running fedora 24.

I see it in lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 010 ID 0bda:8175 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN adapter.
```

With `nmcli dev`, I see the following:

```
DEVICE        TYPE STATE     CONNECTION
lo ...
wlp0s29u1u1u1 wifi unmanaged --
```

If I change it to managed using

```
nmcli dev set wlp... managed yes
```

the status is changed to `unavailable`

If I restart NetworkManager, same.

If I unplug and plug the dongle back in, I see the following in `systemctl status NetworkManager`

```
manager: (wlan0): 'wifi' plugin not available; creating generic device
manager: (wlan0): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
device (wlan0) : inteface index 5 renamed iface from 'wlan0' to 'wlp0s29u1u1u2'
rfkill3: found WiFi radio killlswitch (at .......)
```

My WiFi worked when I installed the os. I actually used the network-install image because my usb-storage was not large enough for the full fedora-server image. What am I doing wrong?

Also, when I first listed my connections, the ap that i used during the installation was listed:

```
NAME     UUID                                    TYPE            DEVICE
SsidName fea2839-fae(not actuall uuid)cdef23422  802-11-wireless --
```

Thanks.

UPDATE: (response to grochmal)

ip addr show :

```
1: lo ...
5: wlp0s29u1u1u2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:hex:w:colons:ff brd ff:ff:...:ff
```

when I use `nmcli dev wiki connect SSID password PASSWORD ifname wlp...`
i get `Error: Device 'wlp0s29u1u1u2' is not a Wi-Fi device.`

Comment: What does `ip addr show` tells you about the interface, also what nmcli command you use to start it (e.g. `nmcli dev wiki connect SSID password PASSWORD iface wlp...`)?

Comment: What is in your `/etc/network/interfaces` file?  If you did a minimal install with your wifi plugged in, it is possible that the installer set up `interfaces` to mention the wifi interface.  Network Manager will not touch any interface mentioned in `/etc/network/interfaces`

Answer (score 1):

Add below lines on /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
```

Then restart network-manager

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: I've found another solutions (if above not working):
on /etc/network/interfaces
# remove everything under [wifi]

Then restart network-manager

Answer (score 0):

For me, it ended up being a rouge netplan: `cat /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`